# Codeigniter form_open()

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I have form_open in view, and I want to send this data to controller, but I don`t know how read and display this data in controller.

```
<?php echo form_open('Login/login'); ?>
 <h4 class="form-signin-heading"> <i class="fa fa-user"> &nbsp Panel logowania: </i></h4>
 <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:7px;" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
 <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  <label class="checkbox">
  <small>
  <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Zapamiętaj mnie
  </small>
  </label>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="submit">Logowanie</button>
<?php  echo form_close(); ?>
```

How dispaly value from input in controller?

Comment: all of the values are passed to your controller as $_POST, read this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 1):

In the Controller you don't have to display data, you just have to get data from the form and manipulate it to save into a Database or to display in another view.

To get data from the form all you have to do is use the input class:

```
$this->input->post();
```

or

```
$this->input->get();
```

based on the method you set in your form.

The best way to do that is use the form helper with the form validation class, in this way you can check the input before to get it in the controller.

Lets use your form, and suppose that this is the controller that generate it:

```
public function login()
{
    //Load library
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //Set the rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if( $this->form_validation->run() )
    {
        //The form is correct
        $email = $this->input->post('username'); //I get this from you form
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        //Do what you need to do
    }
    else
    {
        //Show the form again and in the view handle the error messages
        $this->load->view('login_view')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the POST data in your controller you can use the [input class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) that is automatically loaded by the system.  You want to do the following

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        //Do something with username and password
    }
}
```